# Managing environment specific properties of infrastructure with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, devops, environment

(*[Originally posted DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/10666/19427) but that space seems much less active.*)

**TL;TR:** Assume there are dev, stage and prod environments of Web server infrastructure coded with Terraform. How to ensure each environment runs on different domain with different SSL certificate (on Azure)?

---

Basically, I have learned these [ways to manage Terraform states](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa):

1. Isolation via [Terraform workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)
2. Isolation via file layout

and for each environment (dev, stage, prod) there is a dedicated account(s) on AWS, Azure, etc.

I have also learned about importance of sandbox environment with dedicated account for [manual testing the infrastructure code](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa) locally. I have also read a fair bit about [role of reusable Terraform modules](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d) as well as helpers like the [Terragrunt for working with multiple Terraform modules, and managing remote state](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/).

I think I have grasped quite well how all these puzzles fit into the bigger picture of working with infrastructure but at the code level.

What I'm missing is the how to design detailed aspects of infrastructure in context of development, testing and production workflows and using the different environments.

For example, let's consider a simple infrastructure comprised of:

1. Single virtual network (with necessary subnets, etc.)
2. Web server with (public IP)
3. DB server with (private IP accessible from Web server)

and configured using Terraform in single `main.tf`. The `terraform apply` does the magic, deploys all resources to my (Azure) account and makes the Web server accessible at `example.com`.

I know how to refactor my infrastructure code to introduce the dev, stage, prod environments applying the best practices outlined above.

What I don't know is how to handle environment-specific variables, especially, for networking. That is, for each of the dev, stage and prod environments:

1. Where to keep various secrets, especially for dev and stage?
2. How to manage DNS/FQND settings? Obviously, all environments can not share the same `example.com`.
3. How to handle SSL certificates?
4. How to handle pre-loading database with dev or stage specific data?

Presumably, those are handled with some form of parametrization.

- Which Terraform techniques are recommended for that?
- Are `variables.tf` and `.tfvars` (or equivalent environment variables with custom helper scripts or Makefiles) files per environment directory the good choice?

Comment: As it stands, this question is pretty broad and wouldn't have a single concrete answer. The answer likely differs between different users based on personal preferences. In addition, you have lots of little questions that are hard to give all answers to. I would try to narrow down the scope of the question a bit to a specific problem or error to be solved.

Comment: The background may be presented as broad indeed as I wanted to give complete picture about where I stand in Terraform but the questions are pretty specific: How to manage environment-specific properties like secrets or domain names. It's all single question just asked from several angles.

Comment: I disagree about closing of this. Perhaps Azure MVPs should learn how to read with understanding and a bit about Terraform too, before they blindly judge question is not focused. It clearly asks how to manage environment-specific properties and all those asked in detailed questions (secrets, DNS, SSL) are environment-specific in this context, thus are managed in the same manner. I even give hints to those who'd like to answer.

Comment: I actually thought about answering the question. But you have 4 distinct questions bulleted at the end. I can answer 1 and maybe 2 in the context of Terraform. But 3 and 4 I cannot because it starts to change scope. If you can edit the question to better make it about switching variables per-workspace I'm happy to give a way I handle this. But my answer is specific to Terraform and workspaces and wouldn't be valid for those using Terragrunt and is outside the scope of Azure DevOps. Thus, why I was suggesting to narrow the scope. I'm trying to outline my reasoning for the initial close.

Comment: @AndyShinn How on Earth can I know solution to question 1 and 2 are distinct from those for 3 and 4? If I knew, I would probably not need to ask. I guess that environment-specific secrets and DNS names can be managed efficiently with `variables.tf` files. It is valid to apply transitive property of such  knowledge and presume SSL certs and others can be managed similarly (different paths to certificate files via variables, etc.). If that's not correct, an answer can teach that, clarify OP's misunderstanding, point out distinct solution is needed. Closing just enforces the chicken-egg problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I store all the local variables into a file `local-variables.tf` whose structure is similar to:

```
locals {
  database_ip = {
    staging = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    production = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

  }
  ssl_cert = {
    staging = <staging_path>
    production = <production_path

  }
}
```

Then, you can reference the variable `local.database_ip[terraform.workspace]`
Note that keys of each object of the local variables should reflect the name of your terraform environments.

Comment: It looks like feasible solution for everything that can be file-based declared.